# Handling Dynamic Fields with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, angularjs, reporting-services

Background: I'm working on a project that currently has a SQL Server backend and Angular front end.  The project is a relatively simple forms app, where there are multiple forms that a user can submit to the backend.  Everything works perfectly fine right now but there is a new requirement in the pipeline where they want the future forms to be dynamic.  Dynamic in the sense where they want administrators to be able to add/remove fields from the form without any intervention.

For the prototype I built, I pretty much mocked a nosql db by storing angular-formly json obj that describes the form in one table.  What I'm debating now is how to actually store the results of those forms.  I could just as easily store a JSON result object of those forms in a "single umbrella" form results table.  So essentially take the ng-model and stringify it, and store it in the results table.

Question:

The place where I'm running into issues is with reporting on the results of these forms.  The reports would require reading the data/unpackaging it into a dynamic table and then querying it as requested.  I'm not really familiar with SQL Reporting Services but could I build a generic report that would be able to unpackage the JSON, query it, and generate a report off of it?

Alternatively, is there a recommended SQL Server way of handling this problem or is the way I'm doing it the best way to do it?

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Comment: If you are not tied to SQL Server you might want to have a look at Postgres. It has an extremely efficient key/value store and very powerful JSON support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packing, unpacking and parsing string data isn't in the wheelhouse of most SQL engines.  Approaching it from a SQL point of view, you are essentially storing name:value pairs (the dynamic fields).  I am going to assume all forms will have some minimal common data, at the very least: create data, create user, form id, etc.

So, off the top of my head you'd have:

A table that describes a form: pk, human readable name, list of fields, etc.
A table that stores the non-dynamic fields: pk, form_id, etc.
A table that stores the dynamic fields: form_id, name, value, etc.

Now reporting is a simple query joining across the form desc table, the static table and the dynamic table.

Obviously this is a bit simplistic, but I think you can see where to go with this.  It has the advantage of being very generic and not tied to any front end tech.

Comment: I think I get what you are saying.  Do you mean that I should store the dynamic fields in, what amounts to, a key/value table?  Then create a common_form_field  table that contains the commonalities between forms and join the two to pull back the dynamic data?  That makes sense to me but I was hoping to avoid the write of a new record for each of those dynamic fields...just seems so inefficient to me.

Comment: That was the general suggestion.  How efficient it will be depends on your specific use case.  Are there going to be lots of (different) forms? How many times will a given form be used? a 100, a 100,000? Are reports not run often and this is mostly a write heavy environment? String manipulation is pretty expensive in an SQL engine, joins are not.  Indices on the right columns or view make queries very fast.